# Return "this" of the subclass from superclass C#

Tags: c#, oop

I need to return "this" or the subclass instance from the superclass.

```
interface IA
{
    IA Format();
    void Print();
}
interface IB
{
    IA Format();
    void Print();
    void PrintB();
}
abstract class A : IA
{
    protected bool isFormated;
    public IA Format()
    {
        isFormated = true; 
        return this;
    }
    virtual public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is A");
    }
}

class B : A, IB
{
    override public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is B");
    }
    public void PrintB()
    {
        if (isFormated)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("this is formated B");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("this is B");
        }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new B();
        x.Format().PrintB();
    }
}
```

I have two Classes, class A is superclass and class B is the subclass inherited from A. 
those two classes implementing Interface A and B.

I need to call 'x.Format().PrintB();' just to format the string.

in other words, I need to return the same object in Format() function and based on the changes in the Format() I need to change the PrintB behavior.

so if I created new Class D and inherits A I want to Implement PrintD with different behavior based on isFormated as well.

Comment: You are returning the instance of `B` - there's only one instance at play here - but typed as `IA` so it has no `PrintB` method.  Can you explain more about what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to return 'this' of B but there is something missing in my code. should I implement 'Next()' in the subclass as well?

Comment: is there any relation between `IA` and `IB`?

Comment: Why do you need to use `this` when you already have the instance stored in `x`?

Comment: @Svarr I have use case for this but I tried to make the example simple.

Comment: Why not doing `x.PrintB()` ? Please elaborate your example so that it becomes possible for us to understand your underneath problem.

Comment: As others have noted, your question isn't that clear.  But, I'm guessing that if you either called `Print` (which is virtual and declared in the base class) or defined `PrintB` as virtual in the base class (and overrode it in B) then you'd get what you want. Your `x.Next()` call returns an object that is an object of type `B`, but is typed in your code as an `A`.  Because the compiler sees it as an `A`, your code can only call methods defined on `A`.  If you call `Print` on it, the virtual-ness of the call will result in the `B` implementation of `Print` being called

Comment: guys, I've updated the question and changed the example.

Answer (score 3):

I made A as a generic class take type T and I returned this as T

```
    interface IA<T> where T : class
{
    T Format { get; }
    void Print();
}
abstract class A<T> : IA<T> where T : class
{
    protected bool isFormated;
    public T Format
    {
        get
        {
            isFormated = true;
            return this as T;
        }
    }

    virtual public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is A");
    }
}

interface IB
{
    void Print();
    void PrintB();
}
class B : A<B>, IB
{
    override public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is B");
    }
    public void PrintB()
    {
        if (isFormated)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("this is formated B");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("this is B");
        }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new B();
        x.Format.PrintB();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `x.Next()`, it returns an instance of something that implements `IA`. That could be `A`, `B`, or any other class that implements `IA`, but because it returns `IA`, other classes don't know what the concrete type is. That's usually intentional. If other classes don't know what the implementation of `IA` is then you can replace one with another.

However, since `Next` returns an `IA`, the only way you can call `PrintB` is if `IA` has a `PrintB` method, like this:

```
public interface IA
{
    void PrintB();
}
```

If `A` implements `IA` then it must have a `PrintB` method. But because it's an `abstract` class the method can be abstract. That means `A` doesn't really implement the method. A non-abstract class that inherits from `A` would be required to implement it.

That would look like this:

```
abstract class A : IA
{
    public IA Next()
    {
        return this;
    }
    virtual public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is A");
    }

    public abstract void PrintB();
}
```

`PrintB` doesn't have to be abstract. `A` could implement it. It could be virtual and other classes could override it. Or it could be neither abstract nor virtual, and other classes couldn't override it.

Now, when you declare `B : A`, the compiler will require `B` to implement `PrintB`.

Then you can call `Next().PrintB()` because `Next()` returns `IA` and `IA` has a `PrintB` method.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I've updated the question and changed the example. the case is I need to return the same object in Format() function and based on the changes in the Format() I need to change the PrintB behavior. so if I created new Class D and inherits A I want to Implement PrintD

Comment: It looks like you're most of the way there. A few suggestions. If you actually need the two interfaces, perhaps one can inherit from the other. That way `IB` only declares one new method, not all the same methods that are in `IA`. Next, I wonder how much complication comes from `x.Format().PrintB();` Half your problems might disappear if `Format()` doesn't return anything, and you just do `x.Format(); x.PrintB();`

Comment: Just an afterthought - no big deal - it helps if you use even slightly larger class names. In real life they tend to be more than one letter, so `A` and `B` can be a little confusing to look at. That's why a lot of people use Foo and Bar, Car and Truck, or whatever.

Comment: I am sorry for that, I tried to make the example simple as much as possible. However, I've found a solution for this please check the update.